# example jquery get index/position of sibling

Tags: javascript, jquery, indexing

Let's say I have the following html

```
<ul>
  <li id="a">a</li>
  <li id="b">b</li>
  <li id="c">c</li>
</ul>
<ul>
  <li id="d">d</li>
  <li id="e">e</li>
  <li id="f">f</li>
</ul>
```

If I used jQuery to grab the item `$('#e')`, how do I determine the position or position/index of `e` relative to its siblings `d` and `f`?  In other words, I'm expecting the value 1 (if zero based index) to be returned or 2 (if one based index) because it is the second element in the `ul` list.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Simple: `var idx = $('#e').index() // zero based`

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`.index()`](http://api.jquery.com/index/) to get the zero based index of an element relative to its siblings.

```
$('#e').index();
```

http://jsfiddle.net/LXS9F/

Answer (score 2):

You could also use var idx = `$("#e").prevAll().size()`

Answer (score 1):

You can also try this:

```
$(function() {
    $('ul li').each(function(idx, e) {
        $(this).on('click', function() {
            alert(idx);
        });
    });
});
```

The only trouble is, it'll currently index all `li` on the entire page.

## Edit

This one gives the index of all `li` content.

```
$(function() {
    $('ul li').each(function(idx, e) {
        $(this).on('click', function() {
            alert($('#' + $(this).attr('id')).index());
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getIndex(id) {
    $('ul > li').each(function() {
        if ($(this).attr('id') == id) {
            return i;
        }
    });
    return 0;
}
```